# Searching for second singular solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, singular-solution

I was given the following equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y-4}$ and was asked to solve it and find a family of solutions. I've solved the equation so that $y=\frac{x^2+16}{4}+c$ or $y=\frac{x^2}{4}+4+c$. I've now been asked if I can find a second singular solution not contained in a family. Can someone explain to me what exactly this means? I'm not even sure how to begin going about solving this question, as I'm not sure I understand it.

Much appreciated!

Comment: For $\alpha\ge0$, set $$y(x)=\begin{cases}4&\text{if }x<\alpha\\ \frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{4}+4&\text{if }x\ge\alpha\end{cases}$$
All of them satisfy $$\begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y-4}\\ y(0)=4\end{cases}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you so much for the fast reply! I'm afraid I'm still a bit confused as to what you've done here. Could you elaborate on your reasoning here and why we are suddenly approaching the solution with $\alpha$?

Comment: Not much to elaborate. It's just a notorious example of non-uniqueness of solutions to a Cauchy problem $$\begin{cases}y'=F(x,y)\\y(0)=y_0\end{cases}$$ when $F$ is fails to satisfy the following condition $$" \exists L>0,\ \forall x,y_1,y_2,\ \lvert F(x,y_1)-F(x,y_2)\rvert\le L\cdot\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert "$$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,\,y_0)$. Perhaps the point is that, when you cannot use Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, no one guarantees that you cannot prolongue exotically a constant solution and still satisfy $\frac{dy}{dx}=F(x,y)$.

Comment: you could review the following [Singular solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution#Failure_of_uniqueness)